# Prolog: Not executing code as expected

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

Basically I am attempting to have an AI agent navigate a world based on given percepts. My issue is handling how the agent moves. Basically, I have created find_action/4 such that we pass in the percepts, action, current cell, and the direction the agent is facing. As it stands the entire code looks like: http://wesnoth.pastebin.com/kdNvzZ6Y

My issue is mainly with lines 102 to 106. Basically, in it's current form the code does not work and the find_action is skipped even when the agent is in fact facing right (I have verified this). This broken code is as follows:

```
% If we are headed right, take a left turn
find_action([_, _, _, _, _], Action, _, right) :-
   retractall(facing(_)),
   assert(facing(up)),
   Action = turnleft .
```

However, after some experimentation I have concluded that the following works:

```
% If we are headed right, take a left turn
find_action([_, _, _, _, _], Action, _, _) :-
   facing(right),
   retractall(facing(_)),
   assert(facing(up)),
   Action = turnleft .
```

I am not entire sure why this is. I've attempted to create several identical find_action's as well, each checking a different direction using the facing(_) format, however swipl does not like this and throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If second variant works than difference in last parameter of `find_action/4`. I guess if you'll put there `right` as in first variant it will stop working.
I guess that you can hit "some magic" by using that `retractall/1` and `assert/1`, because you are confusing backtracking there. Your system have side effect, so be sure that once you succeed on `find_action/4` you'll cut your alternatives or will do some counter-measures to restrore initial state of dynamic `facing/1` on backtracking from further unification.
Try to put some traces just after `find_action/4` to see is it really fails or it fails further.